# How to use two forms to search in one and display the records to the other using Visual Basic 2010, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have 2 forms in my visual basic 2010 project. Both are connected with an SQL 2008 Server where i keep a db with customers records(name,surname,address, etc).

What i want to do is to give certain criteria in the first form, lets say name,and hit a search button. The program should search the db if the specified name exists.If it exists i want to show the results in the second form. By results i mean the name , surname, address,etc. If it does not exist i want to prompt the user to insert data into the db.

The problem is that i know how to do this work in a single form but not how to make the two forms "communicate" with each other (meaning that one does the search and the other the projection-adding part).

Any help is appreciated

### Edit

I am sorry guys but i cannot figured it out. I tried setting the filters but all i get is errors. I will post whatever i have written so far in case someone can help me out. So here it is.
As i stated earlier i know how to search for the data in a single form(lets call it DisplayForm). As Olivier mentioned i have textboxes for the records, a combo box with the search criteria(name , surname,id) and a Search button that perfoms the search and populates the text boxes. The code for the search button is this:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim intPosition As Integer


   'Combo box code
    Select Case cboField.SelectedIndex
        Case 0 
            ObjDataView.Sort = "surname"
        Case 1 
            ObjDataView.Sort = "id"
    End Select


    If cboField.SelectedIndex = 0 Then

        intPosition = ObjDataView.Find(txtSearch.Text)
    ElseIf cboField.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

        intPosition = ObjDataView.Find(CType(txtSearch.Text, Integer))
    End If


    If intPosition = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No customer found", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    Else
        objCurrencyManager.Position = intPosition

    End If
End Sub
```

I want this procedure be done in a second form (lets call it FormSearch) and populate the textboxes in form DisplayForm. I know that it is easy enough for someone that knows VB but  i am tottally a newbie and desperatly need help. 
Thanks a lot for any advice

Comment: This is very simple.. what code do you have thus far for your two forms..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your display form add this code

```vb
Public Sub SetFilter(name as String)
   ' Set the filter here
End Sub
```

In your filter form do this

```vb
DirectCast(Application.OpenForms(0), DisplayForm).SetFilter(NameTextBox.Text)
```

Here I assume that DisplayForm is your main form and that it's name is `DisplayForm`. You would call this in a button click event hanlder, for instance.

---

**EDIT** in response to comment:

You said that you know how to do it on a single form. I do not know how you do it, but probably you have textboxes for the name, the address, etc. that you are looking for. Then probably you press a button called `btnSearch`. By pressing this button you trigger

```vb
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch_Click.Click
     ' The search logic goes here
End Sub
```

What I am telling you is to replace `btnSearch_Click` by `Public Sub SetFilter(name as String)` that is public. You would move those search fields and the button to the second form and from there call `SetFilter` of the first form in order to communicate with it and tell it to search a customer. In my example, I pass only a name, but I left it up to you to pass more parameters as required.

Assuming that your customer form is called "DisplayForm", you could access it like this

```vb
Dim cust As DisplayForm
cust = DirectCast(Application.OpenForms("DisplayForm"), DisplayForm)
cust.SetFilter(NameTextBox.Text)
```

My answer was only about the communication between the two forms, assuming that you already managed the other part.

---

Searching for "[VB.NET Tutorial: Working With Data](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=VB.NET%20Tutorial%3a%20Working%20With%20Data&oq=VB.NET%20Tutorial%3a%20Working%20With%20Data)" on YouTube results in six videos on this subject. Video #3 in particular shows how to use filters.

---

**EDIT #2**. Here is a little more help:

I do not know how you are opening the two forms. Since you need a reference to the display form in the search form, it is easier to open the search form as the main form at application startup. At Form_Load in the search form, you then open the display form by code

Code in the **search form**:

```vb
' Reference to the display form
Private _displayForm As DisplayForm

' Create the display form and open it
Private Sub SearchForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    _displayForm = New DisplayForm()
    _displayForm.Show()
End Sub

' Get the search parameters and tell the display form to set the filter
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim field As String, search As Object

    Select Case cboField.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            field = "surname"
            search = txtSearch.Text
        Case 1
            Dim n As Integer

            field = "id"
            If Integer.TryParse(txtSearch.Text, n) Then
                search = n
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for id search", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                Return
            End IF
    End Select
    _displayForm.SetFilter(field, search)
End Sub
```

Code in the **display form** that actually performs sorting and searching:

```vb
Public Sub SetFilter(ByVal field As String, ByVal search As Object)
    Dim intPosition As Integer

    ObjDataView.Sort = field
    intPosition = ObjDataView.Find(search)
    If intPosition = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No customer found", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    Else
        objCurrencyManager.Position = intPosition
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Olivier but can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Thank you Olivier. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Why has "Accepted Answer" been unchecked?

Comment: Please refer to my edited part. I know your answer solves my problem i just can't figure out the filters.

Comment: I added some more explanations. I have simply taken over your filter procedure assuming that it does work. You said that get errors. Can you be more specific?